# How to make columns as in the image using html and css

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgA57.png)Colors - red, green, blue, yellow; Sizes - 5050, 140150.
re-poked everything you can. it is not necessary to use your own display in css to be able to edit as quickly as possible
here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta encoding="UTF-8">
 <link rel="style sheet" href="styles.css">
<title>Rainbow</title>
 </chapter>
 <body>
 <div class="red"></div> 
 <div class="grn"></div>
 <div class="blue"></div>
 <div class="yellow"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the css code

```
.red {
width: 50 pixels;
 height: 50 pixels;
 background color: red;
 display: block;
}
.grn {
width: 50 pixels;
 height: 50 pixels;
 background color: green;
 display: linear;
}
.blue {
width: 50 pixels;
 height: 50 pixels;
 background color: blue;
 Display: linear;
 
 }
.yellow {
 
 width: 140 pixels;
```

Comment: make questions in English.

Comment: [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: First of all, questions need to be in English on Stackoverflow. Second, do not post images of code... Code is text. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76885465/edit) and post it in English (if possible), and include your code as properly formatted text.

Comment: @Siguza Pro tip: `[ru.so]` = [ru.so].

Comment: That CSS isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

I have used **FLEX** which is easier in these kind of situations.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="firstSection">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="grn"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondSection">
        <div class="yellow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .container {
        display: flex; //Flex property is introduced
    }

    .red {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .grn {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: green;
    }

    .blue {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: blue;

    }

    .yellow {

        width: 140px;
        height: 150px; //Since 3 divs on top each other have 50px,then height of this div will be 3*50
        background-color: yellow;
    }
```